# Design DB where primary key of table is also foreign key of another table

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to figure out the best way to design my database. I have 2 tables, `Product` and `Image`.

Product

```
PId PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1)
PName
PPrice
```

Image

```
PId PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
PImage1 
PImage2
FOREIGN KEY (PId) REFERENCES Product(PId)
```

Currently my database is designed in a bad way. Since I assume that whenever an entry into `Product` is added, right after an entry into `Image` is added. This assumption also makes the assumption that the generated primary key for `Image` is the same as the generated primary key for `Product`.

Then in the controller code I have:

```
_context.Product.Add(Product); // Add the created product record to the database

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

_context.Image.Add(imageRecord); // Add the created image record to the database.

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

where, respectively, `Product` and `imageRecord` are objects of the following model classes:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductShortDesc { get; set; }
    public string ProductLongDesc { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    [ForeignKey("Product")]
    [Key]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public byte[] ProductImage1 { get; set; }
    public byte[] ProductImage2 { get; set; }
    public byte[] ProductImage3 { get; set; }
}
```

This begins to fail when I start deleting entries from the tables, and the auto-incremented primary key values no longer are the same.

How can I design it better so that I am able to choose the primary key of `Product`, enabling me to then use this as the primary key of `Image`?

Comment: I do not understand  `This begins to fail when I start deleting entries from the tables, and the auto-incremented primary key values no longer are the same.`.Are Product and Image  configured as  a one-to-one relationship ?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a demo where `Product` and `Image` have one-to-one relationships.

`Image` has set `ProductID` as both PK and FK.

Then add `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]`attribute  on `Image.ProductID` to set the value of PK manually  instead of auto-incremented.

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductShortDesc { get; set; }
    public string ProductLongDesc { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }
    public Image Image { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{        
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public byte[] ProductImage1 { get; set; }
    public byte[] ProductImage2 { get; set; }
    public byte[] ProductImage3 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductID")]
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

controller:

```
_context.Products.Add(Product);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

var imageRecord = new Image()
{
     ProductID = Product.ProductID,
     ProductImage1 = xxx,
     //other properties
};
_context.Images.Add(imageRecord); // Add the created image record to the database.

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Finally, you will create two entities has the same value of PK and cascade delete is used.

Answer (score 0):

In the Image table, I would let it have it's own database generated primary key and leave ProductId as a foreign key only.

If you want to enforce one to one, you can do it via a unique constraint on the ProductId column in the image table.

Even more, you can also live with one table. The reason for creating two tables is to have 1 to N relationship. The tables are also very small in terms of width.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend storing pictures in the server file system. I would also recommend creating a single table with pictures.

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductShortDesc { get; set; }
    public string ProductLongDesc { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }

    public Icollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{        
    [Key]
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public stirng ImageName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductID")]
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Now to get a picture, it is enough to fulfill the request for PruductId from the Images table.

In the future, this will allow you to easily change the number of images. It will also speed up the work of your application, because you do not have to parse the picture.